# How to create debian bundle?

Tags: linux, debian, package

i am new to Debian. so can anybody send a link to Debian source code of configuring and installation. i know all linux commands, but i need step by step explanation to create Debian package  of my project. which includes some jar files and some config files

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

there is *plenty* of documentation on how to create a Debian package:

https://wiki.debian.org/HowToPackageForDebian

if you want to see a real-world example, you can get the code for *any* (official) package, by simply running `apt-get source <mypackage>`. E.g. the following command gets everything needed to create the `hello` Debian package (with the exception of build-dependencies):

```
apt-get source hello
```

This contains both

- the code needed to create the *deb* with `dpkg-buildpackage` (everything contained in the `debian/` subfolder)
- and the original source code (everything outside of the `debian/`) subfolder).

Comment: @ShashidharPatil the way to say thanks on [so] is by accepting and/or upvoting an answer rather than saying "thanks".